# Error implementing EmailServicesFunction metadata

Tags: apex-email-service

I am trying to implement EmailServicesFunction metadatservice but getting error when I execute it in anonymous window.

Error occured processing component NotificationReplyService. An Apex Class must be specified when creating an Email Service. (FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION).

```
public static void crtES(){
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();    
    MetadataService.EmailServicesFunction esf = new MetadataService.EmailServicesFunction();
    esf.fullName = 'NotificationReplyService';
    esf.apexClass = 'ManagedPackage.EmailToTextServiceHandler';
    esf.isActive = true;
    esf.attachmentOption = 'None';
    esf.authenticationFailureAction = 'Discard';
    esf.authorizationFailureAction = 'Discard';
    esf.functionInactiveAction = 'Discard';
    esf.isAuthenticationRequired = false;
    esf.isErrorRoutingEnabled = false;
    esf.isTextAttachmentsAsBinary = false;
    esf.isTlsRequired = false;
    esf.overLimitAction = 'Discard';

    MetadataService.EmailServicesAddress emailAddress = new MetadataService.EmailServicesAddress();
    emailAddress.runAsUser = '0052w00000GIrrM';
    emailAddress.isActive = true;
    esf.emailServicesAddresses = new List<MetadataService.EmailServicesAddress> { emailAddress };
    
    MetadataService.Metadata[] m1 = new MetadataService.Metadata[] {esf};
    MetadataService.SaveResult[] s = service.createMetadata(m1); 
    handleSaveResults(s[0]);               
}
```

ManagedPackage is name of my managed package. can someone please help me with what can be issue over here ?